# ¿Cómo creo un instalador dmg pkg que copie icono y acceso directo en Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos

Quisiera saber si existe algo parecido como crear un instalador `exe` de windows.

Lo único que estoy tratando de hacer es un acceso directo que muestre por defecto el un icono en lugar de la imagen de `safari`.

Probé con `Packages` y leí que hay otros instaladores pero no tengo experiencia en `mac`.

Me imagino que con `xcode` se puede, o no sé si sea tan sencillo como en la terminal.